How do I do instance coloring with nodes in Blender 4.1?
For the life of me, I am unable to get instances of different colors using geometry and shader nodes. From what I've seen of other answers on here, there are two ways to get information from the geometry into the shader: You can connect it to the output node, and then give it a name in the modifier window (I used Colo) or you can use the Named Attribute node to define it (in my case, Colou). Then you put the name in the shader nodes Attribute Node, and it's supposed to carry it over. But it isn't.
Is it clear from the setup I have below what I'm doing wrong?


In the shading editor, the attribute Type should be Instance. I'm guessing that's it ?

Instancer* and make sure it's Blender 3.4 or later.

That's part of it, I'm sure. I fixed that and they boxes all turned red.
I also forgot to divide the factor by the number of boxes so it's in the range 0-1, but even after I do that, they all stay red, so there must be something else going on.

Okay, so I did the division backwards, and that was what I needed to fix the problem. Thank for the help!

...just to be able to mark this question as solved:
Since you are only creating instances here with geometry nodes, the trick in this case is to set the type of node Attribute in the shader to "Instancer".
Something like this:

